# iTextSharp- How to create thumbnail image from first page of a pdf file

Tags: c#, pdf, pdf-generation, itext

I want to create a thumbnail image from the first page of a PDF file. The code I am using is:

```
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(inputFile, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))
{
    using (Document doc = new Document())
    {
        using (PdfWriter w = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, fs))
        {                            
            PdfReader r = new PdfReader(inputFile);                           
            PdfImportedPage importedPage = w.GetImportedPage(r, 1);                            
            iTextSharp.text.Image PdfImage = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(importedPage);                            
            PdfImage.ScaleAbsolute(importedPage.Width / 2, importedPage.Height / 2);
            System.Drawing.Image img = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(new MemoryStream(PdfImage.RawData));
            img.Save(thumbNailImagePath);
            doc.Close();
            r.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Here `PdfImage.RawData` is returning null value. Can anyone tell me what is wrong here? I am new to `iTextSharp`, is it possible to create a thumbnail image of the first page of PDF content using `iTextSharp`?

Comment: iText doesn't convert PDFs to images. You need to look for another library to meet your requirement.

Comment: I'd like to add that the iText tests use Ghostscript to convert PDF files to images. Check the source of the `CompareTool` class on GitHub.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks Bruno and Amedee. Based on your comment, I have used GhostscriptSharp to create thumbnail. It has the method `GhostscriptWrapper.GeneratePageThumb(inputFile, thumbnailPath, pageNo, width, height)` to create thumbnail of particular page.